# characters string to integer

Tags: c

With my program, i need to return the number contained into a string
My program seems to work but to be sure, i need to display the number. Thing is, it looks like it's stuck in ascii
For exemple, if my number is 12, i can only display 1068
I would like tips to be able to display (with the printf or write functions) the number contained in the string "abcd12".
Anyway, here's my program (wich normally displays the value of nbr, iteration per iteration, and his final value into the main) :

```
int my_getnbr(char const *str) {
    int i = 0;
    int nbr;
    int power = 1;

    while (str[i] != '\0') {
            if (str[i] <= '9' && str[i] >= '0') {
                    nbr = nbr * power + str[i] + '0';
                    printf("%d\n", nbr);
                    power = power * 10;
            }
            i++;
    }

    return (nbr); 
}

int main() {
    int nbr;

    nbr = my_getnbr("abcd12");
    printf("nbr = %d\n", nbr);

    return (0); 
}
```

Comment: This exhibits undefined behaviour as `nbr` is never initialised.

Comment: `int nbr = 0; ... nbr = nbr * 10 + (str[i] - '0');`  Subtract `'0'`  (no need for `power`)

Comment: you put `+ '0'` instead of `- '0'`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: i never knew the minus was different from the plus in this case, thx for telling. it worked btw

Comment: this code will not work anyway - as you multiple my multiple of 10 and you  should by 10 only on each iteration

Comment: Not sure what you want. Do you want to get the `12` from `"abcd12"`?

Answer (score 1):

Your concept is good, just a little fine tuning.

- You have not set `nbr`.  Initialize it to zero so you have a known starting point.
- No need for `power`.  Just multiply your number by ten each iteration.
- And the key detail: `'0'` is an *ASCII character*.  If converting to a integer, it happens to be the number 48.  Try this:

  ```
  nbr = nbr * 10 + str[i] - '0';
  ```

That is clear the intent, hardcodes the *meaning* rather than a value, and should get you over the finish line.

A minor note:

- For code clarity, suggest thinking like a mathematician when comparing range values.  You have

  ```
  if (str[i] <= '9' && str[i] >= '0') {
  ```

  which is not wrong, but takes a mental second to say "ah, if it's an ASCII digit.  Whereas, if you reordered like:

  ```
  if ('0' <= str[i] && str[i] <= '9') {
  ```

  the symmetry is more natural, and *visually places* the variable you're testing *between* the bounds.  A small detail, that in anecdotal experience, matters.

Comment: '0' <= str[i] horrible style. Hate it

Comment: @PeterJ_01 you would not be first.  And not horrible style, especially in C.  A _different_ style than you prefer, perhaps.  Consider [primacy of learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_learning#Primacy) as one reason why I like it and you hate it.  But clearly, there's only one "correct" way to do it.  "My way!"  ;-)

Comment: but that code will not work anyway.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 ? Have you tried it?  I have, many times over.  It works just fine.

Comment: Downvoter: Why the downvote, please?

Comment: Works? LOL https://ideone.com/RO2JZj

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157077/discussion-between-hunteke-and-peterj-01).

Answer (score -1):

can be reduced to:

```
nbr = 0;
while (*str) {
        if (isdigit(*str)) 
        {
                nbr *= 10;
                nbr += *str++ - '0';
        }
}
```